# makeObjectsPerformSelector:

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, nsarray

I want to make all objects in an array perform a selector. I've discovered the appropriately named `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` method, but I have a question with it. If I use it on an array, will it change the existing array or return a new one? If it modifies the existing object, what be the easiest way to return a new array with the selector applied?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

makeObjectsPerformSelector: is going to run that selector against every object in the array. If those objects are modified by the selector they will be modified. It does not return anything. Now, there is a catch, which that by default most copies in Cocoa are shallow copies, which means you get a new array, but the underlying objects it points to are the same objects. You will need to use initWithArray:copyItems to make it copy the root level items as well. If you want a new array containing the altered objects as well as the old array do something like this:

```
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray copyItems:YES];
[newArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(doSomethingToObject)];
```

Comment: The selector passed to `-makeObjectsPerformSelector:` takes no arguments. (It's in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).) Yet your selector, as shown, does.

Answer (score 15):

> If I use it on an array, will it change the existing array or return a new one?

No.

First off, read the signature:

```
- (void)makeObjectsPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector
```

`void`, with no stars after it, means “does not return anything”.

Second, note that this is a method of NSArray, which is an immutable class. Therefore, `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` does not mutate the receiving array, because that's impossible.

There is NSMutableArray, and since that's a subclass of NSArray, it inherits `makeObjectsPerformSelector:`. However, if NSMutableArray changed that method's behavior, its documentation would have its own listing for the method (see the many definitions of `init` in various classes' documentation). There's no such listing, so you can safely (and correctly) infer that `-[NSMutableArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]` works exactly the same way as `-[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:]`.

The objects can modify themselves in response to your message, but the array itself will contain the same objects after `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` as before it.

Comment: Yeah. I'm coming to objective-c from ruby, so sometimes I forget about the object typing. I figured out what makeObjectsPerformSelector really does after thinking about it for a while.

Answer (score 7):

Further to other answers, if you *do* want create a new array with the result of calling a method, you can do this:

```
NSArray *derivedArray = [originalArray valueForKey:@"foo"];
```

This will **only** work if your objects can handle a '-valueForKey:@"foo"' message and obviously, is only suitable for methods which take no arguments and return a non-nil value.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm interpreting this correctly...

If you do [myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:someSelector], you're effectively just iterating through myArray and sending the selector message to each object. The array is unchanged because makeObjectsPerformSelector isn't allowed to change its contents.

So in the end, you've got the same array with the same objects.

Comment: Yep. makeObjectsPerformSelector: is pretty much just a shortcut for writing this:
for (id object in array) {
    [object someSelector:someArgument];
}

Answer (score 0):

In following example, You can see one `superView` is created and 10 subview added to it, then to each of them send `removeFromSuperView` (a method which is exist in `view` class) and the result is zero subview in `superView`.

If you familiar with JavaScript and try to find something like `map` in JavaScript, this is not like that. `map` run a function over each element of array and replace it with result but here `makeObjectsPerformSelector` run a method that exist in each object of array.

```
UIView* superView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [superView addSubview:view];
}

NSLog(@"count = %lu", (unsigned long)[superView.subviews count]); // 10
[superView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]; // removeFromSuperview is exist in `view`, you can call [view removeFromSuperview];
NSLog(@"count = %lu", (unsigned long)[superView.subviews count]); // 0
```