# Using NSArray's makeObjectsPerformSelector to have side effects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, side-effects

I have an NSArray of Foos in an Objective-C program. I would like to call the doIt function of each Foo, however, the makeObjectsPerformSelector function of NSArray does not allow the original Foos to be modified, per [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/makeObjectsPerformSelector:). The doIt selector changes the m data member for each Foo when doIt is called. How do I go about efficiently performing this function on each Foo in the NSArray?

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    NSString *m;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *m;

-(void)doIt;

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're allowed to modify the original `Foo`s, just not the array itself.  As you linked to in the documentation:

> The method must not take any arguments, and must not have the side effect of modifying the receiving array.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. After writing the question I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563051/nsarray-makeobjectsperformselector on SO but for some reason it did not show up in the "similar questions" field.