# how to get rid of heading and trailing white spaces from NSString

Tags: iphone

My NSString is like this:

```
NSString *myString =  
(  
“\n \n 24 K CLUB”,  
“\n \n 3 DOLLAR CAFE”,  
“\n \n A PEACH OF A PARTY”,  
“\n \n A ROYAL AFFAIR CAFE”,  
“\n \n AFFAIRS TO REMEMBER CATERERS”,  
“\n \n AFRIKAN DELI”  )
```

**How to get rid of this new line character and white spaces, so that my new string will be like:**
newString:

```
(
"24 K CLUB”,  
"3 DOLLAR CAFE”,  
“A PEACH OF A PARTY”,  
“A ROYAL AFFAIR CAFE”,  
“AFFAIRS TO REMEMBER CATERERS”,  
“AFRIKAN DELI” 
)
```

I tried :

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingstringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];  
myString = [myString stringByReplacingstringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

but unsuccessfully..getting error:

```
[__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7062200
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about [stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:) method?
By *stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]*, it can remove both ends of whitespace and newline characters.

Comment: Save somebody a few seconds:
`[myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];`

Answer (score 0):

Your initial declaration of myString is declaring an NSArray, not a NSString.  Your calls to `stringByReplacingstringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString:` should work on the individual NSStrings. Either iterate the array yourself (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992901/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-nsarray)) to trim the strings, or use `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563051/nsarray-makeobjectsperformselector)) to handle it.

Comment: Ok its an NSArray.  I tried:     NSString *myString = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:myArray] objectAtIndex: 0].. I am able to get array value of 0 index and also able to modify string the way I wanted..now I have this array with huge data..how to do for that...I can't do it individually...how to use foreach loop..I am sorry if my question is to sily..but I am newbie to deal with NSArray and all.