# How to remove the White Space in front of the String in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

```
  NSString *myString = @"     New Profile     "
```

i want to remove the front and end of the White space in my String.

Comment: Always search first then post. This question was asked 2.5 years back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800206/how-to-get-rid-of-heading-and-trailing-white-spaces-from-nsstring

Comment: BTW, where's your ';' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will also remove blank new lines:

```
NSString *temp = @" untrimmed string ";
NSString *newString = [temp stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```