# Selector on multiple objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Is there any provision in objective c so that I can call same selector on multiple object.
Some thing like jQuery does.    I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563051/makeobjectsperformselector) but it requires all objects in array to invoke selector **makeObjectsPerformSelector**.
For example I have following code:

```
[_addButton setTarget:myObject];
[_deleteButton setTarget:myObject];
[_editButton setTarget:myObject];
```

to a line some thing like

```
[_addButton, _deleteButton, _editButton setTarget:myObject];
```

---

I know it is syntactically not making any sense on objective-c, but is there any trick ?

Comment: sure!  makeObjectsPerformSelector

Comment: another common thing is "for all views V in my subviews, if V is a UIButton, do this"

Comment: Another one is .. "for all X in blah, is X **responds to** wah, do x way".  Check out **respondsToSelector** examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer blocks.

```
[@[self.addButton, self.deleteButton, self.editButton] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton* btn, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    btn.target = myObject;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily put your objects in a temporary array and use `makeObjectsPerformSelector` like this:

```
[@[_addButton, _deleteButton, _editButton] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setTarget:) withObject:myObject]
```